# Баннеры не подружились с тёмной темой

Tags: дефект, тёмная-тема

Собственно, вот:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут и без темы все не очень: неопределенность с переходом на ты/вы, непредставленный г-н Чабановский, повторение логотипа из шапки. Как хорошо, что у меня работает Adblock и я этого не вижу.

Comment: Когда-то уже писал в комментах об этом, Николас сказал репортить такие объявления с пояснением «прозрачный фон». Какое-то время репортил, но реакции никакой не последовало) Больше не репорчу.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Мой алгоритм простой: вижу баг - репорчу. Ну а дальше, в этой ситуации мы, это самое, здесь наши полномочия всё:)

Comment: @nomnoms12 Добрый день! Поговорил с ребятами. Они попросили еще раз отправить запрос. Говорят, в последнее время не видели подобных запросов, а старые все обработали. Возможно, где–то закралась ошибка или недопонимание. Пожалуйста, напишите мне если отправите отзыв, чтобы я написал ребятам и они подтвердили, что видят ваш отзыв. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это досадная проблема, с которой без вашего участия мы не справимся. Баннеры сообщества размещены как обычная реклама и находятся в общем пуле объявлений. Если я верно помню, в системе находится несколько сотен разных объявлений. Отыскать вручную все баннеры с прозрачным фоном не представляется возможным.

Чтобы исправить ситуацию, пожалуйста, расскажите нам о конкретных проблемных баннерах. Для этого, когда вы видите баннер с прозрачным фоном, нажмите на ссылку под баннером «Report this ad», выберите причину «Other» и введите пояснение, что фон изображения прозрачный. Наша команда рекламы обработает вашу заявку и поменяет изображение на корректное.

Comment: Что вы скажете об [этом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11100/%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d1%82%d1%91%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9/11128#comment46970_11100)?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Уточнил у ребят, все ли идет по плану. Если что–то изменилось, обязательно отпишусь.

Comment: Я просто хотел сказать, что человек честно репортил о проблемах, но из-за отсутствия минимального фидбека перестал это делать. В итоге проиграли все, как мне кажется.